# Android Refresh UI data from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi i am Using AsyncTask to download Xml's files,images from URl,after downloading xmls i am going to parse and displaying data in ListView of ImageView and TextView.i know how to update UI in
 `onPreExecute() onPostExecute(Void result)`,
    **if for Example  i am downloading 100 xml's in doInBackground() method,i want to update List View for every 10 xml's download completed, i am using Handler to update List view by sending a message.its going to Force close due to 
handlers,can any one suggest me how to do it...** 
Can any one tell me which is the way to solve my prob...

Comment: Show us your code. Show how and there are you creating your `Handler` and how are you using it in `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a Handler if you're using a AsyncTask as it has already a build in mechanism to update the UI thread from the background thread.

You can pass updates to the UI thread using the [onProgressUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) method. As onPostExecute() and onPreExecute() it is also executed on the UI thread. To pass an object to the UI thread you have to call [publishProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) within the doInBackground().

Comment: you are right,but i am fallowing Mvc,so i am downloading data in model class how can i use publishProgress() to update UI.please tell me

Comment: If your AsyncTask is an inner class of you activity then you can access the activity's methods. So you can implement a method in the activity which updates the view by retrieving the data from the model. This method must be called from onProgressUpdate() which in turn is notified after a call to publishProcess() within doInBackground(). Of course have to update the model before calling publishProcess().